# Inaccuracy in SVG?

Tags: svg, adobe-indesign

below you can see a picture of a path in Indesign over a screenshot of the svg in the browser. It's a little hard to see, the lines are completely okay, but the curves are sadly not accurate enough.

XML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="760" height="660"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
      path {fill:white;stroke:black;}
    ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 50.298496904808,177.328388888889  L 164.625988193151,177.328388888889 L 160.222564219419,236.513813861091 Q 108.169653133389,206.464234496512  87.2093550184256,206.99425322761 Q 66.2490569034619,207.524271958709 53.6597040551078,235.630449309736  L 54.9807312472273,200.737549511935 Z" />

</svg>
```

Does anyone know if there is something I can do in order to make it 100% accurate?

[image]
[image: Path]

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you expect. The svg snippet just shows a figure. How is it wrong?

Comment: As I said, in the picture you see, you can see that the curve of the svg is not the same as the indesign path, although it uses the same coordinates of the points and same coordinates for the controlpoints in the curves.

Comment: Same in all browsers? Which of the pngs show what you expect to see?

Comment: I only tested it in Google chrome, as the tool in which we use the xmls run best in chrome. Both pngs are the same, the lower one should just be a little closer. What I "expect" to see, is of course a perfect overlay of both the svg and the indesign path, as the angles of the points are all the same.